# Possible to add a pipe separator after a Kendo Tabstrip item?

Tags: css, kendo-ui

My designer has handed me a rather simple menu, with the menu items being separate by a pipe, so that it looks something like this:

```
Home | About | Members | Contact
```

Depending on where a person is, there could be fewer or more menu items.

Outside of the psuedo :after class in CSS (which IE7 doesn't support and I have to support IE7), is there a way in the Kendo Tabstrip code to add the separating pipe character so that it's not part of the link?

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

Try loading this:

http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

the IE8 version & then supposedly you should be able to use :after

```
a:after {
content: " | ";
}
```

Interesting issue in that IE7 doesn't support :after, but the above script should "fix" that if it doesn't break more.

Comment: No, he cannot. KendoUI menus are generated by the framework so it needs to be done using CSS.

Comment: @OnaBai good to know, I've updated my answer w a work around that would enable :after in IE7 I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a pipe (`|`) or is it possible just a vertical line? If so, try adding the following styles:

```
#menu {
    border-width: 0;
}

#menu > li.k-item {
    border-width: 0 3px 0 0;
    border-color: black;
}

#menu > li.k-item.k-last {
    border-width: 0;
}
```

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/ShRwy/